# A possible new mistake in K&R (second edition) that doesn't appear in any errata?

Tags: c

I think I found  a new mistake in K&R (second edition).

- At page 164, it is written that "feof" returns non-zero if "end of file" has occurred.
- At page 170, it is written that "read" returns 0 when it reaches "end of file".
- At page [176 K&R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhd5M.jpg), there is written the definition of "feof".
- At page [178 K&R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fcbX.jpg), I think that the two conditions marked with red underscore in the definition of "_fillbuf" should be opposite.

Am I right?

Comment: Looks good to me. read() returns 0, which is decremented to -1 before testing (--fp->cnt < 0). So if read() returns 0, fillbuf() sets EOF. Remember that read() returns -1 on error, which becomes -2 in fillbuf's test

Comment: You might actually ask a question about the issue you think you've found that may reference the book but doesn't actually require someone to read the book.

Comment: @RetiredNinja OP posted excellent links to copies of relevant parts of the book.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that book is outdated since more than 18 years and we are neither the authors nor the publisher

Comment: @BjornA.: Possibly violating copyright laws. Nevertheless the question is OT, see ^

Comment: Copyright violation? Nah, Fair Use. http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/what-is-fair-use/ Also, it takes a bold man to call K&R off topic in a C group ;)

Comment: @BjornA.External links can go bad. There should be enough information in the actual question here so nobody is required to click external links and so the question is useful even if they go bad. Even so, this is an extremely narrow question that's unlikely to help anyone with a real problem.

Comment: @BjornA.: US copyright laws are not worldwide applicable. Although Disney & co would like to. And I did not say K&R per se is OT, but the post is. Please read comments carefully. Not ever question about a programming book/tool is on-topic per se.

Comment: p.164 is correct. `feof` returns non-zero if EOF has occured (to be clear, if EOF condition exists as a result of the prior read). p.170 is correct in the sense that if you've read all the data from the file and try to read again (for the first time after reading all the data), the return of `read` will be 0. p.176 defines `feof` as indicating that the `_EOF` flag is present in the flags. And p.178 says that if `read` returns 0, then `--fp->cnt` will be -1, so `flags` will be set to `_EOF` since EOF condition is present. If `read` returns -1 (error), then _ERR. I don't see an inconsistency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with both [Bjorn A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4319483/bjorn-a)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392360/a-new-mistake-in-kr-that-doesnt-appear-in-any-erratasecond-edition#comment77745473_45392360) and with [lurker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980550/lurker)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392360/a-new-mistake-in-kr-that-doesnt-appear-in-any-erratasecond-edition#comment77746492_45392360) — I don't see a problem with the code.

The specification of [`feof()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/feof.html) on p164 corresponds to what the C standard says — although I've linked to the POSIX specification, it is intended to match the C standard.  The specification says that [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) returning `0` indicates EOF; if it returns `-1`, then there was an error rather than simply EOF.  That much is non-controversial.

Note that what's on p176 is *an* implementation of `feof()`; it is **not** *the* implementation of `feof()`.  There are other implementations that differ in detail from this one, though the net result is very much the same.

```
#define feof(p)  (((p)->flag & _EOF) != 0)
```

The macro is unexceptionable; it returns `1` if the `_EOF` bit is set in the flags, and `0` otherwise — that meets the expectations (requirements).

That leaves the sample implementation of `_fillbuf()` on p178.  The relevant code is:

> ```
> fp->cnt = read(fp->fd, fp->ptr, bufsize);
> if (--fp->cnt < 0) {
>     if (fp->cnt == -1)
>         fp->flag |= _EOF;
>     else
>         fp->flag |= _ERR;
>     fp->cnt = 0;
>     return EOF;
> }
> return (unsigned char)*fp->ptr++;
> ```

There are three cases to consider:

- `read()` returns a positive number
- `read()` returns zero
- `read()` returns a negative number

In the first case, the code decrements `fp->cnt` which will be at least `0` so the final return is executed; a character is returned, correctly cast to `unsigned char` to ensure that the value is positive.

In the second case (EOF handling), the code decrements `fp->cnt` from `0` to `-1`, and enters the body of the outer `if` statement.  Since `fp->cnt` is currently `-1`, it sets the `_EOF` bit in `fp->flag` and the count back to zero and reports `EOF`.  This is correct.

In the third case (error handling), the code decrements `fp->cnt` from `-1` to `-2`, and enters the body of the outer `if` statement.  Since `fp->cnt` is not `-1`, it sets the `_ERR` bit in `fp->flag` and the count back to zero and reports `EOF`.  This too is correct.

So, the code in K&R 2nd Edition is correct — you have not found a previously unreported erratum.